# How can I organize my meals to accomodate an evening workout?

Tags: nutrition, post-workout

My workout time is 7pm, when I get out from work and hit the gym. My goal is to loose weight, therefore I don't want to have any meals after 7-8pm. How can I accomodate the meals/snacks surrounding workout in order to keep a healthy nutrition schedule?

What time should I have a pre-workout snack/meal? What should the post-workout snack contain? 
I guess that my main meal of the day would be sometime during the afternoon. 
I am open to any suggestions you have, both for scheduling when to eat and when to eat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not eating after any workout is not a good idea, it brings your metabolism to a grinding halt. Agree with Christopher Bibbs and post workout components.

Without know what time you get up, it is very difficult to give you the exact times, but something like this will work nicely.

7am; 
10am; 
1pm; 4pm; 6pm-light pre-workout carbs; 
8pm

The trick here is to keep your metabolic rate up, therefore lots of mini meals! No food and the body goes into starvation mode and holds onto everything for dear life :[

Keep the engine burning with consistent, steady fuel!

Answer (score 1):

It has been said many times, but bears repeating: weight loss is achieved primarily through diet, not exercise. If you're trying to lose weight, focus on how much and how often you're eating first.

Anyway, the thing you want to do is to keep your metabolism going and not let your body perceive that it is starving. Eating early in the morning after you wake up is a good way to get it started. If you can, eat a meal or small snack every 2-3 hours. Nuts, fruit, some raw vegetables, or what have you. Post workout, have something with a bit of natural sugar (e.g. fruit) within 15 minutes and protein (e.g. skim milk) within 30. Milk is actually a great post-evening workout food because the proteins take a long time to break down and will be present in your body for a good portion of your sleep.